How do I create a highly conductive vapor cloud
I'm working on a project that requires that I create an electrically conductive gas cloud that can conduct voltages as low as 1.5v from a regular double A battery. I've been looking into using mecury vapor since it's a metal and good conductor while also having a low boiling point.
What do you think of this approach and are there any other suggestions? Or how do I achieve this?

Metal vapours are not necessarily more conductive than atmospheric gases. Conductivity in gases relies on the passage of charged ions which take significant voltage gradients to create. You should look into the science of how gas-discharge lamps work to see hints of how to make this easier.

cross-posted https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/815865/how-do-i-create-a-highly-conductive-vapor-cloud

This is a bad idea. Mercury as a liquid or plasma is conductive, but not as a vapor. Light a candle and blow it out. The smoke will be conductive.

Not really conductive for a 1.5V battery.

@JonCuster So only plasma is a gas form that is conductive enough to allow electrons to flow at low voltages?
